# How can I add a button to the stage in flex using only as3?

Tags: visual-studio, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using the Flex SDK within visual studio and trying to dynamically add a button to the stage.  Here is a quick example of what I am doing.

```
public class Test extends Sprite
{                       
    public function Test()
    {
        init();                 
    }                                                               

    private function init():void
    {

        var btnBrowse:Button = new Button();                                        
        btnBrowse.label = "Browse";
        btnBrowse.x = 0;
        btnBrowse.y = 0;
        btnBrowse.width=100;
        btnBrowse.height=100;           
        addChild(btnBrowse);
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to show up and the screen is still empty.  I am importing mx.controls.* for the button.  Could that create an issue since I am not using mxml only as3?

Comment: I assume that you are also creating an instance of Test somehow and adding that to the display list?  The mxml vs. as3 should not be a problem - all mxml gets converted to actionscript under the hood as part of the compilation process, so there isn't anything you can do in mxml that you can't do in actionscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Flex framework controls in an AS3 Only project.  If you are trying to avoid MXML then just create a new Flex Project where the root tag is like:

```
<FooApplication xmlns="*"/>
```

And create a new AS3 Class like:

```
package {

import mx.core.Application;

public class FooApplication extends Application {

// now override something like createChildren to add a button.

}
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right then my options for as3 only are I have to either create a sprite and draw my own button or create the controls in flash and export a .swc.

Comment: There are many ways to create buttons with AS3 only.  But most are painful - thus the reason that most people just use Flex.  There are some lightweight AS3 only frameworks out there that you could also look into like Reflex.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the base class from Sprite to Canvas.